# Resources on multiplexer and demultiplexer?

Tags: analog-to-digital, digital-to-analog, multiplexing

If I search multiplexer in Google and start reading, I find sources that describe a multiplexer as a device that selects between several analog or digital signals, then outputs a single signal. For example, a multiplexer is described as kind of a switch, that just selects one of the input signals.

This seems like a form of multiplexer, but more generally, I always though a multiplexer combined the signals into a single signal then a demultiplexer separates the signals into the separate signals....

So, is a multiplexer just a switch (as defined in the beginning of the Wikipedia article)? Or, does a multiplexer mix signals (e.g., frequency division multiplexing)?

Sorry, I don't know what tags I should select.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of context? There are different kinds of multiplexers for different application areas.

Comment: I suppose referring to the integrated chips, but I was wondering in general, which maybe why I see the variation in definitions.

Comment: OK, can I please ask you to have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer), especially the "See also" section and after that maybe edit your question with the bits that you feel are grey areas?

Comment: Edited. Maybe my confusion is more clear now.

Comment: @Ralff "Multiplexer" is a general term that is used in many contexts. For example, you can have TDM (time-division multiplexing) or FDM (frequency-division multiplexing). You still need to clarify what the context of your question is.